# scaling screencapture fails when I stream over UDP with gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I want to stream my desktop via ximagesrc over UDP.

That works for the complete desktop without any scaling (width, height, framerate), with the program below:

```
gst-launch-0.10 ximagesrc ! ffmpegcolorspace ! x264enc tune=zerolatency bitrate=500 speed-preset=superfast ! queue ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96  ! udpsink host=192.168.0.103 port=5000 auto-multicast=true
```

However when I want to specify the widht,height it fails.

```
gst-launch-0.10 ximagesrc ! video/x-raw,width=320,height=240,framerate=20/1 ! ffmpegcolorspace ...etc
```

Error:
    WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link ximagesrc0 to ffmpegcsp0

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `videoscale` element before your caps:

```
$ gst-launch-0.10 ximagesrc ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=320,height=240,framerate=20/1 !
```

**UPD**
Also, the problem could be with your caps. You can use `-v` flag to get verbose output and check what really goes out of `ximagesrc`.
E.g.

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v ximagesrc \
    ! ffmpegcolorspace \
    ! x264enc tune=zerolatency bitrate=500 speed-preset=superfast \
    ! queue ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 \
    ! udpsink host=192.168.0.103 port=5000 auto-multicast=true

...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstXImageSrc:ximagesrc0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw-rgb, bpp=(int)32, depth=(int)24, endianness=(int)4321, red_mask=(int)65280, green_mask=(int)16711680, blue_mask=(int)-16777216, width=(int)1366, height=(int)768, framerate=(fraction)25/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
...
```

Here I can see that it delivers `video/x-raw-rgb` (not `video/x-raw`).

So to scale video I need a pipeline like this:

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v ximagesrc \
    ! ffmpegcolorspace \
    ! videoscale ! video/x-raw-rgb,width=320,height=240 \
    ! x264enc tune=zerolatency bitrate=500 speed-preset=superfast \
    ! queue ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 \
    ! udpsink host=192.168.0.103 port=5000 auto-multicast=true
```

Comment: After ffmpegcolorspace the format is video/x-raw-yuv so videoscale should be in same format. I will edit your text so it is accurate. A lot of thanks for showing me the way how to troubleshoot these things. This works. Thanks.